# Error on using proguard with Android Facebook sdk 3.0

Tags: android, facebook, proguard, facebook-android-sdk

**Warning:** I removed a lot of "old text" to keep the question more clean. Just check the history if needed.

I'm using `proguard` to both shrink and obfuscate an app that uses the [facebook sdk 3.0](https://developers.facebook.com/android/) (I'm using the [sdk-version-3.0.2.b tag](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/sdk-version-3.0.2.b)). I'm not using a JAR file. Instead, I imported the sdk inside my workspace, as taught by the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/).

At a certain point in the execution, the app loads a [PlacePickerFragment](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/PlacePickerFragment) to let the user choose the place where he is. To code this, I follow exactly the [Scrumptious tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/show-nearby-places/). **When I generate the debug apk without using `proguard` everything works as expected.** But when I generate the signed apk using `proguard`, it crashes when the PlacePickerFragment loads nearby places with the following trace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(27472): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(27472): com.facebook.FacebookGraphObjectException: can't infer generic type of: interface com.facebook.model.GraphObjectList
E/AndroidRuntime(27472):    at com.facebook.model.GraphObject$Factory.coerceValueToExpectedType(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(27472):    at com.facebook.model.GraphObject$Factory$GraphObjectProxy.proxyGraphObjectGettersAndSetters(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(27472):    at com.facebook.model.GraphObject$Factory$GraphObjectProxy.invoke(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(27472):    at com.facebook.widget.$Proxy2.getData(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(27472):    at com.facebook.widget.GraphObjectPagingLoader.addResults(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(27472):    at com.facebook.widget.GraphObjectPagingLoader.requestCompleted(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(27472):    at com.facebook.widget.GraphObjectPagingLoader.access$1(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(27472):    at com.facebook.widget.GraphObjectPagingLoader$2.onCompleted(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(27472):    at com.facebook.Request$4.run(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(27472):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
E/AndroidRuntime(27472):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(27472):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
E/AndroidRuntime(27472):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
E/AndroidRuntime(27472):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(27472):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime(27472):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
E/AndroidRuntime(27472):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
E/AndroidRuntime(27472):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Trying to avoid this error, I kept all facebook classes untouched, but didn't work. My current `proguard-project.txt` file:

```
-keep class com.facebook.** {
   *;
}
```

My current `projet.properties` file (excerpt):

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

As you can see, my `proguard` configuration is a "specialization" of [this file](https://gist.github.com/4148345).

**If I put `-dontobfuscate` in `proguard-project.txt` file, it will work.** But what I don't understand is that the `keep class com.facebook.**` should already prevent classes related to facebook to be obfuscated. Which suggests that the problem is not directly related to the facebook classes.

The [excerpt of code](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/sdk-version-3.0.2.b/facebook/src/com/facebook/model/GraphObject.java#L278) that throws `com.facebook.FacebookGraphObjectException` is:

```
static <U> U coerceValueToExpectedType(Object value, Class<U> expectedType, 
        ParameterizedType expectedTypeAsParameterizedType) {

    // [...]

    } else if (Iterable.class.equals(expectedType) || Collection.class.equals(expectedType)
        || List.class.equals(expectedType) || GraphObjectList.class.equals(expectedType)) {
        if (expectedTypeAsParameterizedType == null) {
            throw new FacebookGraphObjectException("can't infer generic type of: " + expectedType.toString());
        }
    // [...]
}
```

Clearly, `expectedTypeAsParameterizedType` is `null` in release build. But in both builds (debug and release) `expectedType` is a `com.facebook.model.GraphObjectList` interface. Unfortunately, I don't understand almost nothing about Java reflection concepts.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This will solve your problem, i hope:

And the winner is .....

```
-keepattributes Signature
```

From Proguard Homepage:

> The "Signature" attribute is required to be able to access generic
>   types when compiling in JDK 5.0 and higher.

Answer (score 15):

if you want to proguard Facebook, the config below is working for me

```
#modify for Facebook
-keepattributes Signature
-keep class com.facebook.model.** { *; }

-keepnames class * implements java.io.Serializable
-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    !static !transient <fields>;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}
```

Comment: only this full solution work for me `-keepattributes Signature` didn't solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

This may work (untested)

```
-keep class com.facebook.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
-keep class com.facebook.** {
   *;
}
```

The reason being, is that when specifying private, public, protected you're still opening up default (package private) access to obfuscation.