# Publish not working in Facebook SDK 3.0 with proguard

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, proguard, facebook-android-sdk

My android app works perfectly when used without Proguard, but when used with Proguard I do get the `user_info` permission but am not getting the `publish_actions` permission.

I even tried

```
-keep class com.facebook.*
-keep class com.facebook.android.*
-keep class com.myapp.classcallingfb
```

but this too did not help.

I even tried upgrading to FB Android SDK 3.0.1 but it did not work.

Can you please suggest a solution to this problem, a hacky solution would suffice just so that I can still use Proguard and protect my code.

Comment: Did you also try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13538070/error-on-using-proguard-with-android-facebook-sdk-3-0

Comment: @MingLi Yup, this solution worked when combined with the above three but not independently. Post it as an answer. I ll accept it. Thanks a ton, this issue was irritating me like anything.

Comment: @MingLi Can you please answer this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15966376/how-to-post-on-the-wall-of-a-page-using-facebook-android-sdk-3-0  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting link as answer. Combine answer in the other question with what you have above.

This is mainly because there some code in the SDK that uses reflection to make graph requests, and that doesn't jive well with Proguard.

[Error on using proguard with Android Facebook sdk 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13538070/error-on-using-proguard-with-android-facebook-sdk-3-0)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same Problem, but in my case the problem was not proguard. The api key changed after signed export.

My solution was to figure out the new key. Look here (step 2):

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-facebook-sdk-android-development-part-1